# How to use ioctl() from kernel space in Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is it possible to call `ioctl` from a Linux kernel module?
Can anyone provide an example of how it's used?

Comment: You aren't really supposed to do things like that.  If you do a search, you will find somewhat implementation-dependent code for how to do an arbitrary syscall from within kernel space, but please think if there is a way to accomplish your real objective without breaking the model like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to call `sys_ioctl`.
It's exported if the kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_COMPAT`.

Or, if you have the device driver's `struct file_operations`, you can call its `ioctl` handler directly.

However, the ioctl handle would expect pointer parameters to be in the address space of the process currently running, not in the kernel address space. `copy_from_user` would be used to read them. If you give pointers to the kernel address space, `copy_from_user` will fail. I don't see how you would get around this.

**Edit:**

If you will call ioctl handler between below code than `copy_from_user` will not ever fail.

```
 mm_segment_t fs;

  fs = get_fs();     /* save previous value */
  set_fs (get_ds()); /* use kernel limit */

  /* system calls can be invoked */

  set_fs(fs); /* restore before returning to user space */
```

Comment: ioctl handler in file_operations has been deprecated. Can you figure out newer way to use ioctl?

Comment: Can you elaborate how get_fs() and set_fs() magically allow the kernel space to execute system calls, and how after this "copy_from_user()" no longer creates a problem?

Comment: `set_fs` affects the mechanism that validates that addresses passed to `copy_to_user` are indeed in the current user's address space. It makes the kernel think that the current address space is the kernel address space.