# How to use KVM (kernel base virtual machine) API from the kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm

I have to run a piece of code in **VMX-non** root mode, using **KVM API**. This can be easily done by using [KVM API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/api.txt) from a user space program. But, I have to do this from the kernel space itself. Sending required data to user space and running a user space program isn't an option.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11132906/981766) post mentions a way to issue ioctl calls from the kernel space, and since the KVM API uses **ioctl** calls to interact with KVM kernel module, it seems like a plausible approach. However, I couldn't understand the approach, and am not sure if it will work in an error free manner.

Does KVM expose an API which can be run from the kernel space itself? If not, how can I make a user space program which receives required data from the kernel space (lot of data structures), and then does the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is already Qemu which is a user space program that interacts with KVM through ioctls. Everything you need is supported by Qemu.

You can just extend Qemu to implement easily your KVM application as a Qemu command.

Take a look at hmp-commands.hx file in Qemu root directory for examples.